# backup msSQL stored proc or UDF code via Python

Tags: c#, python, sql-server, stored-procedures, smo

The idea is to make a script that would get stored procedure and udf contents (code) every hour (for example) and add it to SVN repo. As a result we have sql versioning control system.

Does anyone know how to backup stored procedure code using Python (sqlAlchemy, pyodbc or smth).

I'v done this via C# before using SQL Management Objects.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to access SMO from Python (because there is no generic solution for accessing .NET from Python), so I would write a command-line tool in C# and call it from Python using the `subprocess` module. Perhaps you could do something with `ctypes` but I have no idea if that's feasible.

But, perhaps a more important question is why you want or need to do this. Does the structure of your database really change so often? If so, presumably you have no real control over it so what benefit does source control have in that scenario? How do you deploy database changes in the first place? Usually changes go from source control into production, not the other way around, so the 'master' source of DDL (including tables, indexes etc.) is SVN, not the database. But you haven't given much information about what you really need to achieve, so perhaps there is a good reason for needing to do this in your environment.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Structure of a DB doesn't change often. SP's and UDF source change. I have SVN to control PHP source. In case with sql I find it easier not to have a pre-production source control. For me it's easier to backup SP's automatically and review changes or restore source on demand.

Comment: One other option I forgot to mention is IronPython, which would make it very easy to access SMO. On the other hand, it's a completely different implementation of Python so it might not fit well into your environment.